# AWS-S3-CRT -how to configure response timeout and abort

Tags: amazon-s3

The aws-s3-crt doesn't have any timeout for putobject request and getObject request.
The aws-s3 - we can use configuration class to set timeout, but in case aws-crt -  the configuration class doesn't contain and timeout configuration.

I want my s3-crt library to be configuring timeout for put and get, how do I achieve that, also if possibke how to cancel as well - the running connection - if network or any issue in my application

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/1882

After digging the blogs and source, There was a issue and fixed in latest version, hope it helps someone